# decompiling an asp.net site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, decompiling, reflector

hallo all

i have an asp.net site which i have no source code for it.

anyway i would like to decompile the whole site and that way i can work on it agian.

how can i decompile an entire website easily to c# and not do it file by file with feflactor?

please help me with this, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [File Disassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx) plugin for Reflector.  It'll let you dump out a whole assembly into code files all at once.

There's another plugin: [FileGenerator](http://filegenreflector.codeplex.com/), that looks like it'll do the same thing, and generate a project file for you to boot.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Decompiler.NET in the past. It does a very nice job.

[Decompiler.NET](http://www.junglecreatures.com/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=3&tabid=3)

Hopefully you have permission to Decompile this code.

Answer (score 0):

In the time passed a number of new and much better options became available. JustDecompile and DotPeek are up to date free decompilers that are definitely up to the task of decompiling and asp.net site.

ILSpy should also be capable of doing this although it seems work on keeping it up to date is slowly coming to an end. dnSpy is a more obscure alternative for assemblies that have been somehow processed/modified after compilation, e.g. by obfuscator or IL optimizer, etc.