# Updating a DLL in an aspx

Tags: asp.net

I am an old ASP programmer that recently took a job that has ASP.NET.  I have an aspx file that has this at the top:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Default.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="List.aspx.cs" Inherits="itnola.List" %>
```

And the area that I'm most interested in is this line of code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dplDistrict" runat="server" Width="205" DataValueField="districtID"
                                DataTextField="districtname">
```

There is a table in the database called districts that if I make a modification to that table it displays the changes in this dropdown. However, there is an extra entry in the drop down I assume they have hardcoded.

Not being familiar with ASP.NET, I've looked for a List.aspx.cs file and do not find it anywhere on the server.  I did find an itnola.dll file in a bin folder I suspect may have something to do with this.  If I remember correctly from my Visual Basic days this dll file is "compiled" and therefore not editable correct?  How do I remove this one line in the drop down?

Comment: Are you sure List.aspx.cs doesn't exist in a different folder?  That's the code behind reference there, and I suspect there is some code pertaining to that dropdown.  Look in APP_CODE maybe?  It's *somewhere*

Comment: You have to find out where it is coming from...is it from a `UNION ALL` clause on the database side: `SELECT Blah FROM MyTable UNION ALL Select Foo`.  Is it from the client side code (js, etc) or is it from server side asp.net (dropList.Items.Add(new listItem("blah"));`

Comment: Try right-clicking on List.aspx in the Solution Explorer and select "View Code". This should bring up the .cs file. Also, in the top menu of the Solution Explorer, look for a button that has a tool tip called  "Show All Files". This will allow you to see the .cs file when you click on the + icon next to the aspx file.

Comment: Andrew - I searched both C and D drives, no luck.
JonH - I cleared out the table completely and the one entry remained in the drop down, so I don't think this is occuring.
@Shai Cohen - I thought you might be my savior! Unfortunately when I pull the .aspx file into Visual Studio, I see a "Solution Explorer" window on the top right, it is empty and the icon for "Show All Files" is grayed out.

Comment: Ah! So you are not actually opening the project? Are you looking at the _deployed_ files? You won't find the .cs file there, because it has already been compiled into the main dll file. If this is the case, you need to find the original source code contained in the project, not the code that was deployed to the web server.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Unfortunately i'm afraid I don't have access to the original source code. It was developed by a developer that no longer works for the company. I've looked over his hard drive and have not been able to find it.  Do you have any advice on what might help me find it on his drive? maybe it's under a common file extension or something?  Appreciate your help Shai!

Comment: Do you have any source control at the company (Visual Source Safe (VSS), Team Foundation Server (TFS), Subversion, etc)? It might be in there. Otherwise, you may need to decompile the site. It's not pretty, but I believe it is possible. Try this link from SO: [decompiling an asp.net site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153664/decompiling-an-asp-net-site). You can also try Googling for **Decompiling asp.net website**. HTH. And I feel for you.... :)